# Typescript Autocomplete Narrowing

Tags: typescript, types, autocomplete, union

Attempting to understanding how Typescript autocompletion limits to the allowed types. Given a union of strings, Typescript's autocomplete will list on the available types; however, with a union of Class types, it seems to provide all legal and illegal values. Can someone explain why?

[image: Example]

Here is playground with an example: [Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgNnA0gOwPYHdkDkYFsIDOYMAxtALxQDkAygAoB0AKocAIxVQA%2019zrAJioBuALAAoCTABGBYACdSwKCTgwCBKACF10AN4SoRmXMUll8iDAAmqZHBBRkeQsTIAuWAhQZsLoqQQYuIAvhKq6poA8sjQEAAewBDI1po6BNBQBuJGUJY2dg5O-m4UvIwschwSYeIRGlBM6KhQCUkpabpZhrlG%20bb2js74AWRQlLQVrNWSoeFqDUwAFpZxicmp2l3ZvX1WA0XDroHj5fxyQjUSEqCQUACqyACWdgDCC5qUMdA8TS2-KwgQRu4GgjxefhGpVO4LeHwA2lQjqMIFQALpQYLXcQJMCoeTKW7QADiEGAAFFkMAnqAAJKQ45kAA8PSM91a6w6D2edhwUMCEgAfDCech3pEOe1Nk9kAAzCDyKDk1lQAD8SslG00sLFHxVvXV5MRyNK6M1XPu%20t2RnVSqt1s8sQAbgr7VBHRAXfIVR6vVjZhIAPSBqAAdSWjlshBUVPkcCgAGooCinKhlHAnrgaVBgEtoE6YPInjI4NAYLKkorc3EAI4AV3gyaeAHNkDmWtWoIVHKXm42iQQgyGtHXlCRY-GkymM1ngJpOzAC081NJS12wNS7JoZTnQVBrIQSEWN-iADStBjNhhQABEfEqwAYbBv4S3yhgo9QJFQuDApaSOrihonikhSVI0iA9J8oyEBMpM5zsFQwqUFAQA)

**--Edit 1 --**
It was suggested that the devil may be in the details...of the type-context vs. the value-context; however, the latest playground shows the same situation happens on either side of the equal sign

[Playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgNnA0gOwPYHdkDkYFsIDOYMAxtALxQDkAygAoB0AKocAIxVQA%2019zrAJioBuALAAoCTABGBYACdSwKCTgwCBKACF10AN4SoRmXMUll8iDAAmqZHBBRkeQsTIAuWAhQZsLoqQQYuIAvhKq6poA8sjQEAAewBDI1po6BNBQBuJGUJY2dg5O-m4UvIwschwSYeIRGlBM6KhQCUkpabpZhrlG%20bb2js74AWRQlLQVrNWSoeFqDUwAFpZxicmp2l3ZvX1WA0XDroHj5fxyQjUSEqCQUACqyACWdgDCC5qUMdA8TS2-KwgQRu4GgjxefhGpVO4LeHwA2lQjqMIFQALpQYLXcQJMCoeTKW7QADiEGAAFFkMAnqAAJKQ45kAA8PSM91a6w6D2edhwUMCEgAfDCech3pEOe1Nk9kAAzCDyKDk1lQAD8SslG00sLFHxVvXV5MRyNK6M1XPu%20t2RnVSqt1s8sQAbgr7VBHRAXfIVR6vVjZhIAPSBqAAdSWjlshBUVPkcCgAGooCinKhlHAnrgaVBgEtoE6YPInjI4NAYLKkorc3EAI4AV3gyaeAHNkDmWtWoIVHKXm42iQQgyGtHXlCRY-GkymM1ngJpOzAC081NJS12wNS7JoZTnQVBrIQSEWN-iADStBjNhhQABEfEqwAYbBv4S3yhgo9QJFQuDApaSOrihong6nyjJlNQVBAA)

[image]

Comment: I haven't verified that this is the reason, but autocompletion contexts are completely different. The type and value spaces might well have different completion algorithms, but the only other valid conceivable type would be an alias like `type T = 'SP.Test1'`, so what would be the point of offering it. For values, you might use a type assertion to override the checker potentially making an value "valid", and it does list the best candidates first.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for the quick response...I considered that as well; however, as seen in the edited post the situation exists in both contexts (type vs value)...additionally, first giphy the order of suggestion doesn't appear to coincide with the best to worst suggested types...as the first "Base" class doesn't satisfy the constraint...

Comment: I'm not saying that the behavior is consistent. I believe literal types are handles in special ways for ease of use. `Base` is a candidate because it is the top level constraint in `GetEntityNamespace<T>`.